# CSS ul height difference

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj2PA/) of my issue:

How could I make the `ul` columns the same height and not dependent on how much data is included inside them.

**CSS:**

```
#priceTable{
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:gray;
}
#priceTable ul{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 40px 0 0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:195px;
    background:orange;
}
#priceTable li{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
                        <div id="priceTable">
                            <ul class="rowOne">
                                <li class="rowName">Package</li>
                                <li>1</li>
                                <li>2</li>
                                <li>3</li>
                                <li>4</li>
                                <li>5</li>
                                <li class="button"><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="rowTwo">
                                    <li class="rowName">Package</li>
                                    <li>1</li>
                                    <li>2</li>
                                    <li>3</li>
                                    <li>4</li>
                                    <li>5</li>
                                    <li>6</li>
                                    <li class="button"><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="rowThree">
                                        <li class="rowName">Package</li>
                                        <li>1</li>
                                        <li>2</li>
                                        <li>3</li>
                                        <li>4 </li>
                                        <li class="button"><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
                                        </ul>    
                            </div><!-- end #priceTable -->​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Javascript to do this. There are many HTML/CSS techniques that can handle this problem. A simple Google search turned up [articles](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/) [like](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) [these](http://woorkup.com/2009/10/11/really-simple-css-trick-for-equal-height-columns/).

Yes, these describe `<div>`s instead of `<ul>`s but the techniques are still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The onlu way to do this with CSS is to set them all a fixed height. Instead of your `min-height : 100%` use something like `min-height: 300px`. But since you do not know how much data each of the `uls` will contain, this is a very inflexible solution.

Now, If you want all your columns to have the same height, than i supose you want them all to be as tall as the tallest one.

This jQuery code should do the trick:

```
var equalHeight = function ( group ) {
    var tallest = 0;

    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if( thisHeight > tallest ) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });

    group.height( tallest );
}
```

And than just call it on document ready with your group of elements

```
$(function () {
    equalHeight($('.rows'));
});
```

Working example here => http://jsfiddle.net/y2eHg/

Answer (score 0):

Hard solution is setting fixed height in pixels with `overflow: hidden`